# When is it suggested to write a second answer instead of appending the contents in the first answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

When is it suggested to write a second answer instead of appending the contents in the first answer? *Specifically for Politics SE.*

If I have to describe the situation here, I answered a question [yesterday](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/66271/33033). It isn't correct completely. I don't think I should delete it as well because it contains useful information. Now I am willing to write another answer, which might be correct. Both answers contain useful information.

The question is about superlative degrees. Such questions are difficult to answer. If I [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/66274/33033) a number today, chances are someone [surpasses](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/66291/33033) mine someday. That doesn't mean the information is not useful. So, I wish to keep the information of the previous answer as well.

Another example would be [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/60341/33033).

So, for these type of questions, is it allowed to write a second answer?

Comment: Are you asking about appending *your own* answer or about appending the answer written by *another* user?

Comment: Appending my own answer (second) to my own answer (first) @Philipp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that it's fine to post them together (i.e. in the same answer) if there haven't been a lot of votes and the answers are somewhat complimentary. For example, you would see this with *why* questions where answerers give a few different reasons in the same answer.

In this case, the new answer is really different (it considers different countries) and it stands on its own. Another user could have written that second answer and then it would be fine as well.

The two main criteria in your consideration would be:

- Do you want users to be able to vote on the answers separately? That's only possible if they're different answers.
- Is the new information sufficient to answer the question on its own? In other words, does it not rely on the previous answer?

Related question on main Meta: [*What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209).